# Python if else condition in one line syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I know this question has been asked lots of times but I still cannot get the syntax right to get it to one line:

```
string = 'abcdea'
ab = []

for c in list(string):
    if c in ['a','b']:
        ab.append(c)
```

One line (does not work):

```
ab.append(c) if c in ['a','b'] for c in list(string)
```

Comment: That problem isn't really suited for a *conditional expression*. You're trying to use the wrong tool for the job. You could use a list comotehsion like below, or just keep it as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
string = 'abcdea'

ab = [c for c in string if c in 'ab']

print(ab)
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

For the one-line syntax, the `else` suite is required (e.g. `ab.append(c) if c in ['a','b'] else pass for c in list(string)`). However, statements are not permitted as operands in the syntax.

You're looking for [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (e.g. `ab = [c if c in ['a','b'] else None for c in list(string)]`). However, that could put `None` in your list, which I don't believe that you want. List comprehensions have special syntactic sugar for these situations. You simply move the test expression to the end (e.g. `ab = [c for c in list(string) if c in ['a','b']]`).

In your particular case, another approach is to use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter). This can be particularly helpful for situations in which the test function is lengthy or complicated. See the following for an example:

```
def is_valid_char(c):
    return c in ['a','b','c','d','e','f','A','B','C','D','E','F']

ab = list(filter(is_valid_char, list(string)))
```

Lastly, strings are iterable, so there's no need to convert one to a list for this purpose (e.g. `ab = filter(is_valid_char, string)`).